# Return array object in asp.net WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I want to create WEB API which sends input to Angular. I want to send data in JSON format as an *array*.

Below is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("GetEmployeeByID")]
public Employee Get(int id)
{
    Employee emp = null;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        emp = new Employee();
        emp.ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
        emp.ClientName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
    }
    return emp;
}
```

**Actual output:**

```
{"ClientId":15,"ClientName":"Abhinav Singh"}
```

**Expected output:**

```
[{"ClientId":15,"ClientName":"Abhinav Singh"}]
```

Comment: you are returning a single object. Send a list of employees and add that employee to the list.

Comment: The actual output is correct if you should stick with the rest principles. If you ask for a user by Id, you don't expect to get a list in return..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code return only a single element. Change it to return a collection by using **`List`**   as follows,

```
  public List<Employee> Get(int id)
    {
        Employee emp = null;
        List<Employee> _employees = new List<Employee>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            emp = new Employee();
            emp.ClientId = Convert.ToInt32(reader.GetValue(0));
            emp.ClientName = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
            _employees.Add(emp);
        }
        return _employees;
     }
```